# Leaflet marker.cluster Popup on the geojson data loaded by leaflet ajax

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I want to create a leaflet map to display site locations. The site data was loaded by `leaflet ajax` in the geojson format.

Then I use `Leaflet.markercluster` to create a cluster view and it works fine. But it seems the popup only shows the last site, no matter which icon I click on.

Here is my original code

```
function map_viewer(map, options){

        var my_data = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_data/",{
            onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.siteid);

            clusters.on('click', function (e) {              
            this.bindPopup(feature.properties.siteid); 
            });
            }

        });

        var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
        my_data.on('data:loaded', function() 
        {
        clusters.addLayer(my_data);
        map.addLayer(clusters);
        });
        
        

        var groupedOverlays = {
          "Layers": {
            "cluster view":  clusters   
          }
        };

        L.control.groupedLayers(groupedOverlays).addTo(map);
    }
```

***Updated on 2021-02-01:***

I realise there are a few similar cases after go searching on google. However, when I refine my code based on the suggestion, the popup window never show up anymore:

```
    function map_viewer(map, options){
            var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
            var my_data = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_data/",{
                onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.siteid);
                }
    
            });
    
            my_data.on('data:loaded', function() 
            {
            clusters.addLayer(my_data);
            map.addLayer(clusters);
            });
    
        }
```

Also, please refer to below a small part of the importing geojson dataset.

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": 
{"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"siteid": 1, "latitude": -28.004959, "longitude": 153.428117, "pk": "1"}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [[153.428117, -28.004959]]}}, 
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"siteid": 2, "latitude": -33.870436, "longitude": 151.225013, "pk": "2"}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [[151.225013, -33.870436]]}}, 
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"siteid": 3, "latitude": -33.92677, "longitude": 151.21356, "pk": "3"}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [[151.21356, -33.92677]]}}, 
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"siteid": 4, "latitude": -33.854711, "longitude": 150.987657, "pk": "4"}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [[150.987657, -33.854711]]}},
```

***Conclusion:***

I have fixed the issue just by converting the geometry type in my geojson dataset from "Multipoint" to "Point". It seems this plugin `Leaflet.markercluster` can only cluster view for Multipoints, but not able to display the bindPopup of each layer.

Comment: Please post your solution as a answer, this will help other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fo me it is clear why the popup has the last id, because in the `onEachFeature` function you bind/overwrite every time the popup to the clusters with the new siteid and so the last one is applied.

But when you add a popup to the the complete markercluster all layers have the same popup.
So change your code to:

```
        var my_data = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_data/",{
            onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
               layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.siteid);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can’t see the Popup windows anymore after changing to your code.

Comment: Look into this example, here are the popups showing: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/nc2ky6uh/ or do you want to have popups or the clusters but then you need to ask you, where should the cluster know which siteid they should have and the clusters are created dynamicly while zoooming

Comment: Hi @Falke Design, your example is exactly that I want to achieve on my map. I want to see clusters, then a popup window to show site id when I click a specific icon. I have posted my modified code, the only different thing seems to be that the example is using jQuery but I am using Ajax to load geojson data.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I delved into this case for 2 day, eventually, I find the bug and fix it.

The geometry type in my geojson dataset is "Multipoint". It seems this plugin Leaflet.markercluster can only cluster view for Multipoints, but not able to display the bindPopup of each layer.

To fix this, I just need convert "Multipoint" to "Point.

Anyway, thanks heaps @Falke Design for your kind hints and the great example.

Comment: Clustering the Layer Groups from GeoJSON MultiPoint geometry should work fine, on the contrary of binding popup.